# How to find string in dataframe and create a new one?

Tags: python, pandas

In Python 3 and pandas I used the command below to create a new dataframe.

In the "empresas_brasil" dataframe, in column "nome_empresa" I look for all the lines that begin with the word "CONSULTORIA".

```
consult = empresas_brasil[empresas_brasil['nome_empresa'].str.startswith("CONSULTORIA", na=False)]
```

The format of the dataframe looks like this:

```
empresas_brasil.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8952217 entries, 0 to 8952216
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Unnamed: 0      int64
cnpj            int64
nome_empresa    object
estado          object
dtypes: int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 273.2+ MB
```

But now I need to create another daframe that finds the word "CONSULTORIA" anywhere in the column "nome_empresa", not just the beginning

Please, does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change `startswith` by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
mask = empresas_brasil['nome_empresa'].str.contains("CONSULTORIA", na=False)
consult = empresas_brasil[mask]
```